# mongo not found error even after path setup

Tags: database, mongodb

```
mongo : The term 'mongo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ mongo
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (mongo:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

help me to run mongo and mongod please

Comment: what sever version?